# scaling x-axis in ggplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have an Object classt of `xts`. I would like to plot this object with `ggplot2`

my `xts`object:

```
structure(c(463829L, 469849L, 608148L, 470825L, 560057L, 431183L, 
418000L, 508168L, 422579L, 589829L, 462264L, 487183L, 612174L, 
467904L, 454620L, 450243L, 549898L, 422026L, 508311L, 385633L, 
420200L, 619074L, 462605L, 465353L, 565804L, 464841L, 505977L, 
624608L, 491175L, 459701L, 563406L, 461595L, 499607L, 674799L, 
505167L, 637375L, 500131L, 473494L, 488527L, 613972L, 468938L, 
454034L, 566511L, 456879L, 592797L, 491368L, 481690L, 597927L
), .Tsp = c(2012, 2015.91666666667, 12), class = "ts")
```

I woulf like to have also month numbers on my plot. I have tried this code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(zoo)
library(scales)
autoplot(as.zoo(a2)) + geom_line()  
+scale_x_date(format = "%b-%Y")
```

but I get this error:

```
Error in continuous_scale(aesthetics, "date", identity, breaks = breaks,  : 
  unused argument (format = "%b-%Y")
```

What should I do to do this job? Like this plot but with month:
[image]

Comment: I have edited my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that the index to your time series is in decimal date (i.e., numeric) format, and `scale_x_date` is expecting something in date format.

Here's some code that gets close to what I think you want. It involves creating a `zoo` object with the index in date format first, then plotting that. Like:

```
a3 <- zoo(a2, order.by = as.Date(yearmon(index(a2))))
p <- autoplot(a3)
p + scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month")
  + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

I think you'll want to tinker with the options in `scale_x_date` to improve the look of the result, but this should get you on the right path, I think.

Comment: if I try your code, I get this error: `Error in continuous_scale(aesthetics, "date", identity, breaks = breaks,  : 
  unused arguments (date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%m %Y")`

Comment: Huh, it works for me. Anyway, I made a minor revision that might fix the problem you're still having. Give it a try?

Comment: Tnx for your hints. This code doesn't work for mee too, but I have found the soloution. I think we are using different version of `ggplot2` in my version there is no `date_breaks ` instead I should use this code: `breaks = date_breaks("2 months")`

Answer (score 1):

Simply try this:

```
a2 <- read.table(text=' Jan    Feb    Mar    Apr    May    Jun    Jul    Aug    Sep    Oct    Nov    Dec
                 2012 463829 469849 608148 470825 560057 431183 418000 508168 422579 589829 462264 487183
                 2013 612174 467904 454620 450243 549898 422026 508311 385633 420200 619074 462605 465353
                 2014 565804 464841 505977 624608 491175 459701 563406 461595 499607 674799 505167 637375
                 2015 500131 473494 488527 613972 468938 454034 566511 456879 592797 491368 481690 597927', header=TRUE)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
a2$year <- rownames(a2)
a2 <- melt(a2)
ggplot(a2, aes(variable, value, group=year)) + geom_line() + facet_wrap(~year, ncol=1)
```

with output 
[image]

or all in one plot:

```
ggplot(a2, aes(variable, value, group=year, col=year)) + geom_line()
```

with output 
[image]

or this:

```
a2 <- read.table(text=' Jan    Feb    Mar    Apr    May    Jun    Jul    Aug    Sep    Oct    Nov    Dec
2012 463829 469849 608148 470825 560057 431183 418000 508168 422579 589829 462264 487183
                 2013 612174 467904 454620 450243 549898 422026 508311 385633 420200 619074 462605 465353
                 2014 565804 464841 505977 624608 491175 459701 563406 461595 499607 674799 505167 637375
                 2015 500131 473494 488527 613972 468938 454034 566511 456879 592797 491368 481690 597927', header=TRUE)
a2$year <- rownames(a2)
a2 <- melt(a2, id='year')
a2$date <- as.Date(paste(a2$year, a2$variable, '01'), '%Y %b %d')
ggplot(a2, aes(date, value)) + geom_line() + 
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "months", date_labels = "%b %Y") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

with output
[image]

Comment: I would like to have all in one plot

Comment: I have also updated my post. What I am looking for. I would like to show the month also in x-axis

Answer (score 0):

test this option in the ggplot.

```
+scale_x_date(labels=date_format("%Y-%m")
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the class of `a2` is not `"xts"` -- it is a `"ts"` class object.  Anyways, first convert the index to class `"yearmon"` and then use `scale_x_yearmon` like this:

```
z <- as.zoo(a2)
index(z) <- as.yearmon(index(z))
autoplot(z) + scale_x_yearmon()
```